# Laravel 5.4: 500 ISE without any error output

Tags: php, apache, laravel, http-status-code-500, laravel-5.4

I've been recently working on a laravel app and when I finished it, I decided to upload it to a server through FTP. I've set up all the proper folders in the storage/ directory and chmodded them to 777. ModRewrite is setup on the server, but I still get a 500 ISE without any log stack displayed in browser. I don't have access to Apache logs, so cannot check what's wrong. Please, could you give me some suggestions on what can be wrong and how to fix this? (The app was working absolutely fine on my local server on PC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working by executing:

```
php composer.phar dump-autoload
php composer.phar install
```

(The second one only generated optimized class loaders, because everything was installed earlier)

Answer (score 0):

php artisan key:generate

Assuming permissions are right, I'd say it has to do with missing encryption key.

Comment: Thanks for the suggest, but how can I do it if I don't have access to anything except FTP?

Comment: Never mind, got it working using a webconsole grabbed from github